# Large .pkl data for backend is not pushed in github

Tags: github, machine-learning, deployment, backend, large-files

I am learing ML. recently, I have made movie recomandation model from tmdb dataset, I processed data using that model in .pkl (binary) file. made backend using that data but, data is too large to push in github I am unable to host website.

I am trying to push the backend with processed data but unable to deploy since it exceed the limit of file size

Answer (score 0):

`git` think git's not very useful tool for saving large files, more suitable is `DVC`, you just need

```
dvc init
dvc remote add -d remote_storage path/to/your/dvc_remote
dvc add model.plk
dvc push
```

more about in [docs](https://dvc.org/doc/use-cases/versioning-data-and-models/tutorial)